# SurroundContents on a range spanning multiple tags (getRangeAt problem?)

Tags: javascript, text, range, selection

I have a script that (I think) needs to use surroundContents to wrap the selection area. Doing so allows me to append something, and then reassign the range as the selection.

I believe I've narrowed the problem down to a misuse of getRangeAt, but I'm not quite sure how to correct it.

Here's the brief bit of code:

```
        function getRangeObject(selectionObject) {
        // Moz
        if (selectionObject.getRangeAt) {
            return selectionObject.getRangeAt(0);
        }
```

And here's line 89 where it throws an error at me:

```
rangeObject.surroundContents(newNode);
```

And of course, here's the error:

> Error: uncaught exception:
>   [Exception... "The boundary-points of
>   a range does not meet specific
>   requirements."  code: "1" nsresult:
>   "0x805c0001
>   (NS_ERROR_DOM_RANGE_BAD_BOUNDARYPOINTS_ERR)"
>   location:
>   "http://www.latentmotion.com/insertNode/index26.html
>   Line: 89"]

If it's helpful to see the whole thing, you can view the script (so far) here:
http://www.latentmotion.com/insertNode/index26.html

And the text selection helper that I was going off of was quirksmode - which doesn't detail the use of multiple ranges, [located here](http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/range_intro.html).

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: can you kindly help me out with how you solved the problem ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the error message describes the problem well. [This section of the DOM Range spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Traversal-Range/ranges.html#Level-2-Range-Surrounding) describes what leads to an exception being thrown by a `Range` when using `surroundContents`.

Comment: Yeah - that might be it. I read the spec you linked to, but am still unsure of how to fix the problem. Is there some way of cleaning up / completely selecting the non-text node that throws the error?

Maybe I could detect the partially selected node and somehow close it out?

Comment: It might help if you said more precisely what you're trying to do. What do you want to append and where?